# React Functional Component's state gets reset with setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can someone please help me understand why this variable `requestCount` gets anchored at 0? I expect that it will increment every 3s but instead it doesn't.

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [requestCount, setRequestCount] = useState(-1);

  const doSomeWork= () => {
    setRequestCount(requestCount + 1);
    setTimeout(doSomeWork, 3000);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={doSomeWork}>Click</button>
      {requestCount}
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Some knowledge should be known first: [Why am I seeing stale props or state inside my function?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#why-am-i-seeing-stale-props-or-state-inside-my-function)

You have two options:

1. Use [Functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):
2. Use [`useCallback`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) with dependencies to create new `doSomeWork` every time when the `requestCount` state changes. So that the `doSomeWork` will read the latest `requestCount` state instead of stale value. And, you should execute the macro task queued by `setTimeout` using `useEffect()` hook with `doSomeWork` dependency. Because we need to wait for the execution of `useCallback` to complete and create a new `doSomeWork` function so that the macro task(`doSomeWork`) will read the latest `requestCount`.

The below example shows these two options:

`SomeComponent.tsx`:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';

export const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [requestCount, setRequestCount] = useState(-1);
  // should execute macro task queued by setTimeout
  const ref = useRef(null);

  // option 1
  // const doSomeWork = () => {
  //   setRequestCount((pre) => pre + 1);
  //   setTimeout(doSomeWork, 3000);
  // };

  // option 2
  const doSomeWork = useCallback(() => {
    setRequestCount(requestCount + 1);
    if (ref.current) return;
    ref.current = true;
  }, [requestCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      setTimeout(doSomeWork, 3000);
    }
  }, [ref.current, doSomeWork]);

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={doSomeWork}>Click</button>
      {requestCount}
    </>
  );
};
```

Unit test:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import { SomeComponent } from './SomeComponent';

describe('70297876', () => {
  test('should pass', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
    const { container } = render(<SomeComponent />);
    expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<div>
  <button>
    Click
  </button>
  -1
</div>
`);
    const button = screen.getByText('Click');
    fireEvent.click(button);
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000);
    });

    expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<div>
  <button>
    Click
  </button>
  1
</div>
`);
    act(() => {
      jest.advanceTimersByTime(3000);
    });
    expect(container).toMatchInlineSnapshot(`
<div>
  <button>
    Click
  </button>
  2
</div>
`);
  });
});
```

Test result:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/70297876/SomeComponent.test.tsx
  70297876
    ✓ should pass (36 ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   3 passed, 3 total
Time:        3.865 s, estimated 4 s
```